# can update data in sqlite, android

Tags: android, sql-update, android-sqlite

i want to update my data in sqlite.. i have profile mainpage. in the page got 3 button(add,view,edit). in the edit page, i can retrieve data from sqlite and display it, 
now, what i want to do is, when the user edit and save it, it will update the sqlite.

below are my activity code and db code

```
public class ProfileEdit extends Activity 
{
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ArrayList<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private DBHelper helper;
Button btnSave;
EditText addAddress, addHeight, addDrName, addDrContact,
         addGuardianName1, addGuardianContact1, addGuardianName2, 
         addGuardianContact2, addHospitalName, addHospitalContact;
TextView viewName, viewDOB, viewBloodType;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile_edit);

    btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

    addAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    addHeight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    addDrName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    addDrContact = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    addGuardianName1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    addGuardianContact1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    addGuardianName2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    addGuardianContact2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
    addHospitalName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
    addHospitalContact = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText12);

    viewName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    viewDOB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dobbtn);
    viewBloodType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText5);

    helper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = "select * from " + DBHelper.TABLE_PATIENT;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);

    try{
        if( cursor != null ){
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
               do {
                   idList.add(cursor.getInt(0));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(1));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(2));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(3));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(4));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(5));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(6));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(7));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(8));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(9));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(10));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(11));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(12));
                   list.add(cursor.getString(13));
               } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){  
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    viewName.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    viewDOB.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    addAddress.setText(cursor.getString(3));
    viewBloodType.setText(cursor.getString(4));
    addHeight.setText(cursor.getString(5));
    addDrName.setText(cursor.getString(6));
    addDrContact.setText(cursor.getString(7));
    addGuardianName1.setText(cursor.getString(8));
    addGuardianContact1.setText(cursor.getString(9));
    addGuardianName2.setText(cursor.getString(10));
    addGuardianContact2.setText(cursor.getString(11));
    addHospitalName.setText(cursor.getString(12));
    addHospitalContact.setText(cursor.getString(13));
    cursor.close();

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String address = addAddress.getText().toString();
            String height = addHeight.getText().toString();
            String drname = addDrName.getText().toString();
            String drcontact = addDrContact.getText().toString();
            String guardianname1 = addGuardianName1.getText().toString();
            String guardiancontact1 = addGuardianContact1.getText().toString();
            String guardianname2 = addGuardianName2.getText().toString();
            String guardiancontact2 = addGuardianContact2.getText().toString();
            String hospitalname = addHospitalName.getText().toString();
            String hospitalcontact = addHospitalContact.getText().toString();

            helper.updateDataProfile(database, 1, address, height, 
                    drname, drcontact, guardianname1, guardiancontact1,
                    guardianname2, guardiancontact2, hospitalname,
                    hospitalcontact);
            Toast.makeText(ProfileEdit.this, "Successfully Edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent i = new Intent(ProfileEdit.this, ProfileMain.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}

public void onClickCancel(View v){
    startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileView.class));
}
 } // end class
```

this is my code for DBHelper for update

```
public void updateDataProfile(SQLiteDatabase db, int id, 
            String address, String height, String drname, 
            String drcontact, String guardianname1, String guardiancontact1, 
            String guardianname2, String guardiancontact2, String hospitalname, 
            String hospitalcontact)
    {
        ContentValues editProfile = new ContentValues();
        editProfile.put(ADDRESS, address);
        editProfile.put(HEIGHT, height);
        editProfile.put(DRNAME, drname);
        editProfile.put(DRCONTACT, drcontact);
        editProfile.put(GUARDIANNAME1, guardianname1);
        editProfile.put(GUARDIANCONTACT1, guardiancontact1);
        editProfile.put(GUARDIANNAME2, guardianname2);
        editProfile.put(GUARDIANCONTACT2, guardiancontact2);
        editProfile.put(HOSPITALNAME, hospitalname);
        editProfile.put(HOSPITALCONTACT, hospitalcontact);
        db.update(TABLE_PATIENT, editProfile, PATIENT_ID + " = " +1, null);

    }
```

Comment: well I will start non hardencoding the id of db row  you need to update . Then what`s your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use This Pattern for update and provide PATIENT_ID=id ;

I hope it will work .

'db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_jobid + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getjobid()) });'